# How does k-fold cross validation select variables?

Tags: multiple-regression, cross-validation, variable

I am trying to create a model and then validate it. I  have 130 observations, with 10 variables. I am sure many of the variables are not needed. When i do a stepwise lm in r (AIC), it ends up determining the model requires 3 variables and has an r2 of .75. The variables it selects make sense (predicting resting energy expenditure (DV) in humans using lean mass, fat mass and gender (IVs)).

Now i am doing a cross validation (repeated k fold) to assess the validity/performance using the variables the stewpise procedure determined. Is this a sensible way of developing and testing the model?

I read that cross validation methods are used for variable selection, but I dont see how this works? When i run a kfold or repeated kfold, or LOO in r using the caret package, it always generates a model based on the IV's i tell it to use. it doesnt eliminate any useless variables. What am i not understanding about cross validation variable selection?

Comment: are you using stepwise in each fold?

Comment: i dont believe so. Sorry, im a bit of an r/model building noob. Im an exercise scientist/ dietitian, trying to learn R for research. This is my code for running the kfold cv

> data_ctrl <- trainControl(method = "CV", number = 10)

> rmrmodel<- train(rmr ~ lean + fat + gender,
+                      data = ree,
+                      trControl=data_ctrl,
+                      method="lm",
+                      na.action = na.pass)

Comment: i just did some more reading and i worked it out. downloaded the mass package and changed method = "lm" to method = "lmstepAIC". now it makes sense. but now im wondering, withall the critiques of stepwise selection, what else to use?